# Пользователи на смартфоне

Tags: java, android

Можно ли как-нибудь получить доступ к пользователям смартфона(либо создать новый)?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html - оно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для получения данных о пользователях устройства (не путать с аккаунтами на устройстве) вы можете использовать [UserManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html)(доступен с API 17)

```
UserManager um = (UserManager) context.getSystemService(USER_SERVICE);
List<UserHandle> userHandles = um.getUserProfiles(); //метод доступен с API 21
```

Возможно, для работы с этим классом нужно разрешение

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS"/>
```

Которое, к сожалению, доступно только для системмных приложений.

Comment: То есть создать нового пользователя не получится?

Comment: @kapmayn, я думаю, что не полуится. И это, в общем-то, не странно. Я бы не очень хотел, чтобы какое-либо приложение могло управлять пользователями на моем устройстве.

Comment: на самом деле можно , для это нужен аккаунт AccountAuthenticator, разрешение AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS, сам менеджер куда добавлять, ну и разрешения на его работу.